# how to use wildcard in renaming file in oracle directory

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

Is it possible to use wildcard on renaming a file from a directory?

```
UTL_FILE.FRENAME (

   'EXT_DIR' IN   VARCHAR2,

   '%.CSV%'  IN   VARCHAR2,

   'EXT_DIR' IN   VARCHAR2,

   'WPP_ACCOUNT.CSV' IN   VARCHAR2,

   TRUE);
```

Comment: There are some other ways to loop through the files in a file system : check this http://www.pafumi.net/SQL_Directory_Listing.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. This is not a database call. You could create an external table, with a preprocessor directive that gives you the list of files in a directory, then put a `FOR` loop on top of that, but that's fairly complicated.

Comment: I see, that is why on my other question unfortunately the external table im using is not working when I use preprocessor.